# getting the "element not a compile-time" constant error

Tags: objective-c

I am writing the following piece of code which gives following error

```
@implementation ViewController
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"paul",@"cyrus",@"victor",nil ];
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 }
```

I am getting the "Initialization element not a compile-time constant" on the line where i have declared the "myArray"..

Note that i am initializing the array in the ".m" file and not the ".h" file.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize a global or static variable you have to use a compile-time constant. Basically the compiler will have to write that value to the object file. Your code is sending multiple messages, which can only be done at runtime.

If this really has to be a global variable you'll have to initialize it in some method. `+initialize` often is used for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned, you have declared a global variable.

you can use a simple function instead:

```
static NSArray * NamesArray() {
  return [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"paul",@"cyrus",@"victor",nil];
}
```

it's probably not what you want, and completely unnecessary to create a global, but you can in fact initialize a global `NSArray` using a container literal expression if you're compiling your source as Objective-C++:

```
// requires Objective-C++
static NSArray * const arr = @[@"paul",@"cyrus",@"victor"];
```

because this array and its elements are not difficult to create, you should:

- just use a function
- or an ivar if you need to cache and access it often

if it *were* really expensive to create, then you might favor this form:

```
// requires Objective-C++
static NSArray * Names() {
    static NSArray * const arr = @[@"paul",@"cyrus",@"victor"];
    return arr;
}
```

because it will not be constructed until you need it. global initialization can be very problematic.

Comment: Are you sure the container literals work for globals? They're just translated to constructor method calls, AFAIK -- it's not like an `NSString` where the compiler knows the object's layout.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter thanks bunches +1. i spend most of my time with ObjC compiling as ObjC++. i have noted where ObjC++ is required.

Comment: Whoa, so it _does_ work for C++?! That's awesome. I'm going to have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Make myArray an ivar and initialize it in the appropriate place, or create a static global in your class and initialize it in the "initialize" class method.